# How to write an Upstart script for a background service (db)?

Tags: server, scripts, upstart

I am on Ubuntu 14.04 server and I am trying to write a script for my database. I have added the file `/etc/init/neo.conf`. The file is the following:

```
description "neo4j upstart"

start on startup
stop on shutdown

script
  echo $$ > /var/run/neo_start.pid
  exec /home/ubuntu/neo/neo4j-enterprise-2.3.1/bin/neo4j start
end script

pre-start script
  echo "[`date`] Neo4j Starting" >> /var/log/neo.log
end script

pre-stop script
  rm /var/run/neo_start.pid
  echo "[`date`] Neo4j Stopping" >> /var/log/neo.log
end script
```

`sudo service neo start` works fine but `sudo service neo stop` tells me: `stop: Unknown instance:`.

Any ideas? Maybe something to do with the PID?

Comment: Where does `neo_start.pid` come from?

Comment: Do you solve this problem? Can you post a script example please?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `bin/neo4j start` creates it's own daemon process that upstart loses sight of. If you use `bin/neo4j console` upstart will be able to keep track of it like a normal process.